# JDBC executeQuery showing Error without reason

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am writing a simple JDBC program using MySQL but Whats' WRONG with one line. I don't see any thing wrong but below mention line showing error while running the program

Code -

```
ResultSet recs = psmt.executeQuery("select * from item_master where catid = "+id1 +"and des = '" +sString+"';");
```

Error -

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'des = 'LG computer' ' at line 1

I also test this query in MySQL and got the output -

```
select * from item_master where catid = 2 and des = 'LG computer';
```

But Java not allowing me execute this line. I also tried with LIKE

```
select * from item_master where catid = 2 and des LIKE 'LG computer';
```

Comment: I suggest you print the string that you're passing to `executeQuery()` -- the problem will be evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space after the `int`, and you don't need a semicolon in the query. Something like,

```
"select * from item_master where catid = "+id1 +" and des = '" +sString+"'"
```

**or**

```
String.format("select * from item_master where catid = %d and des = '%s'", 
        id1, sString);
```

**or**, my preference, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

```
String query = "select * from item_master where catid = ? and des = ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
   ps.setInt(1, id1);
   ps.setString(2, sString);
   try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
       // ...
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Frisch Thank you so silly I am, I think I have to visit Eye Specialist.